# How do I use the get request of axios by sending a query from the user and getting the values from the database for that particular query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

```js
function AdminMemberSearchFirstName({ name }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQ] = useState("");

  function queryGiven(query) {
    setQ(query);
  }

  async function getFilteredData() {
    axios.get(`admin/member/firstname/${query}`).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setData(data);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredData(name);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <FirstNameForm queryGiven={queryGiven} />

      <h1>{query}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using axios to get the data from the database using the given API. Instead of using the query variable, if I use the actual name, then it works. When I use the query variable, I think it passes an empty string when the page loads because of which I get 400 error code in the console. The value of query comes from the FirstNameForm component, and that one works. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: _"if I use the actual name, then it works"_... what does this mean? Where is `name` supposed to come from in your code?

Answer (score 0):

1. `name` is not defined anywhere. If you want to pass a value, pass `query`
2. If you want to make the request when `query` changes, list it in the effect hook dependencies
3. If you don't want to make requests for empty `query`, then wrap the call in a condition

```js
// this could even be defined in another module for easier testing
const getFilteredData = async (name) => 
  (await axios.get(
    `admin/member/firstname/${encodeUriComponent(name)}`
  )).data;

useEffect(() => {
  // check for empty query
  if (query.trim().length > 0) {
    getFilteredData(query)
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  } else {
    setData([]); // clear data for empty query
  }
}, [ query ]); // this effect hook will run when query changes
```